# classList.remove() is not working. Shake the button everytime

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, addeventlistener

I Am creating the **Letter Counter** which shows how many letter you have typed.***If letters Number is greater than 10 then it shake the button,and background changes to red.***

But When letter Number is greater then 10 It shake only ones.

**• Please Understand My Issue Clearly -** I want that When the letters number is greater than 10 ,the number may be 11,12,13
**every time** it should be shake.

**••Case** - Letter Number = 11 [Button Must Shake] [Ok Shaked ].
*Now I Added Some More Characters, letter number becomes 15 ,But it doesn't shake* 
**Why?**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="textArea" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div class="counter">Letter Count : <span> 00</span></div>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.querySelector('.textArea').addEventListener('keyup', runCount);

function runCount(e) {
let shakeEle =document.querySelector('.counter');
let span = document.querySelector('span').style;

let number = e.target.innerText.length;
document.querySelector('span').innerText =number;
shakeEle.classList.remove('shake');

if (number>10) {
  span.background='red';
  shakeEle.classList.add('shake');
}
else{
  span.background='#000';
}
}
```

**CSS**
The Class "shake" I am adding when number is greater than 10

```
.shake{
  animation : shake 0.2s;
}
@keyframes shake{
  0%,50%,100%{position: relative;left:0px;}
  25%{position: relative;left: -10px;}
  75%{position: relative;right: -10px;}
}
```

**See Whole Code At Codepen**
https://codepen.io/adi45code/pen/RwGdMwO

*It Should Shake Every Time When Number Becomes greater than 10. Please Help*

Comment: Maybe remove the class "shake" first (programatically)so that when you add it, you get the desired result. If it was already added and did it's thing, why should it know to do it again? if that class is already present?

Comment: GetSet ,I Using that also still not working

Comment: Well that wont work, my last comment. Apparently the animation is just done and requires another hack to get it back to the beginning.

Comment: GetSet, Ohhhhh ,I Understand Bro......Lots of thanks....

Comment: This link here (just found) might be relevant to your needs: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/      .... My internet search was "reset keyframes on css"

Comment: Getset,I was Doing By setTimeout method,but you provided me a best article about it. Really Thanks 

Comment: No problem. I did your fiddle. And I did the search and that article came up. Figured I'd share.